# Bazel test `ImportError` Relative Import

Tags: python, bazel

When I run `bazel test :all -- --test_output=all` I get:

> ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package

I have tried doing a relative import like so:

```py
from .pose import Pose
```

I then tried using the absolute import, using the directory name which does contain a `__init__.py` file:

```py
from pose_format.pose import Pose
```

But then I get:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pose_format'

---

Running the second configuration using pytest (built in PyCharm) works, while the first one doesn't.

Is there a way to let bezel know what is the relative module structure?